# Parâmetros e variáveis entre componentes [Ionic + Firebase]

Tags: firebase, ionic2

estou com uma dúvida aparentemente simples.

- Tenho um projeto conectado ao firebase. Neste caso específico, tenho uma listagem *ngFor de cervejarias na página "cervejarias.html" onde eu puxo todos os nós principais do JSON /cervejaria.
  [image: cervejarias.html]
  [image: cervejarias.ts]
- Um dos childs com informações que eu chamo é o {{cervejaria.referencia}} que me dá um valor diferente para cada item. Por exemplo, no nó que possui a cervejaria Hot Rod, o valor é "hotrod".
- Dito isso, eu gostaria que, ao clicar no botão 'ver cardápio', eu direcionasse para a página 'cervejaria-inside.html' onde, através de um parâmetro passado, eu puxe os dados dos childs relativos ao nó daquela cervejaria específica.
  [image: cervejarias-inside.html]
  [image: cervejarias-inside.ts]
  [image: JSON exemplo com os dados]
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar o objeto todo como parâmetro em sua função.
Na sua página *cervejarias.html* eu aconselho mudar o nome que usar no *ngFor pois vc está usando "cervejaria of cervejaria", isso pode dar conflito até mesmo para você identificar se está usando a cervejaria do loop ou cervejaria o array de objetos.
fica melhor:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let cerveja of cervejarias | async">
```

Dessa forma da para entender que quando usa "cervejaria", no plural, vc está usando o objeto do loop, que corresponde a apenas uma cervejaria e seus parâmetros e quando usa "cervejarias" é o array com todas as cervejarias. Nessa caso na sua função ionViewDidLoad teria que trocar o array "cervajaria" por "cervejarias".

Pelo o que vi do seu código vc está trazendo todas as informações da cervejaria nesse array, sendo assim, vc pode passar o objeto "cervejaria" todo para sua próxima página. basta mudar sua função navigate()

```
<button ion-button icon-left clear item-end (click)="navigate(cervejaria)">
```

No arquivo cervejarias.ts deve alterar a função também:

```
navigate(objSelecionado){
    this.navCtrl.push(CervejariaInside, {
        parametroReferenciaEnviado: objSelecionado
    })
}
```

Na sua cervejaria-inside.js vc receberá no navParams.get("parametroReferenciaEnviado") vc já terá o objeto com todos as dados da cervejaria.

```
this.cervejaria = navParams.get("parametroReferenciaEnviado")
```

Se precisar usar a referência é só usar this.cervejaria.referencia